# MFC structure array

Tags: c++, arrays, mfc, structure

I would like to create an array of structure in C++. I do not know the size so I would like to make it dynamic. I have tried with CList but I have failed. So I tried using a vector but I have the same error.

I have the following structure in my header :

```
typedef CArray<CArray<double, double>,double> ObjectArray;
struct MyStruct {
  CString type;
  CString name;
  ObjectArray value;
};
std::vector<MyStruct> ST;
```

In my cpp file, I have the following code to populate my array. STR is a structure I populated beforehand.

```
ST.push_back(STR);
```

I have the following error when building:

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxtempl.h(262): error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject

I guess I am doing something wrong but I do not understand what I am missing.

Comment: what is the type of `STR`? `MyStruct` (should be)?

Comment: better show how you populate STR...

Comment: probably the `copy-constructor` is `private`, but nothing can be said by seeing your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of mixing MFC containers with STL containers, why not use `std::vector` throughout?

```
#include <vector>
typedef std::vector<std::vector<double> > ObjectArray;
struct MyStruct {
    CString type;
    CString name;
    ObjectArray value;
};

std::vector<MyStruct> ST;
```

The `CString` is OK (CString has its uses, and is also copyable).  However in this day and age, using the MFC containers instead of STL containers is rarely, if ever necessary.  I have read that even Microsoft doesn't use them anymore in their C++ based programs and now only use the STL containers.

Comment: Thank you very much. As everybody said the mixture MFC/STL is the source of the error. By replacing my ObjectArray with a STL container, I have no error anymore. I will try to stick to the STL container in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you derive a class from `CObject`, you have to provide a custom copy constructor, see here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st9cdfkz.aspx

"The standard C++ default class copy constructor does a member-by-member copy. The presence of the private CObject copy constructor guarantees a compiler error message if the copy constructor of your class is needed but not available. You must therefore provide a copy constructor if your class requires this capability."

I guess `CArray` inside the struct generates the problem, as it is derived from `CObject` and does not define a custom copy constructor, see here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4h2f09ct.aspx

Either don't use it, or derive some `CDerivedArray` from `CArray` and define a custom copy constructor there.

Why don't you use `std::vector` or `std::map` or another STL class rather than `CArray`?